# Resetting position of e-puck in Webots using Supervisor node - problem with getting a handle to the robot

Tags: mobile-robot, simulator, webots

I am writing a method (Java) that will reset the position of e-puck in Webots. I have been following tutorial on [Supervisor approach](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-8-the-supervisor). I have two controllers in my project:

- SupervisorController extends [Supervisor](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor) - responsible for genetic algorithm and resetting e-puck's position
- EpuckController extends [Robot](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) - drives the robot

Robots are communicating via Emitter and Receiver, and everything works fine but the position reset.
This is what I'm doing in SupervisorController:

```
412 Node epuck = getFromDef("epuck");    
413 Field fldTranslation = epuck.getField("translation");
```

And as a result I get this exception:

```
[SupervisorController] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
[SupervisorController]  at SupervisorController.initialise(SupervisorController.java:413)
[SupervisorController]  at SupervisorController.main(SupervisorController.java:497)
```

epuck variable is null. I tried calling different methods on epuck, and they all resulted in NullPointerException. The name of e-puck matches the world file.

```
DEF EPUCK DifferentialWheels {
  translation 0.134826 -0.000327529 0.107963
  rotation 0.0244439 0.999246 -0.0301538 1.95838
  children [
  (........)
  ]
  name "epuck"
  controller "EpuckController"
  axleLength 0.052
  wheelRadius 0.0205
  maxSpeed 6.28
  speedUnit 0.00628
}
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to get a handle to the robot or where to look for issues in simulation/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solid nodes (including Robot and Supervisor nodes) have a DEF name, like any other node and it is usually written in upper-case. These nodes also have a field "name". Both may be used by a Supervisor, it depends on which function is called.

In my case, the function getFromDef() expects a DEF name as argument, and not the name from the "name" field. The DEF name of my e-puck is "EPUCK" - hence modifying controller to:

```
Node epuck = getFromDef("EPUCK");
```

solved the problem.